# How to continually refresh an image from disk that is being written to from another thread/program

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, image, mvvm

I have some legacy C/C++ code that I am trying to quickly integrate into my GUI (CLI is not an option due to complexity and time-constraints). It is continually outputting an image at `~15fps` from a camera. My idea was to write the images to disk and read it from my program with the GUI which uses C# and WPF. The image being written to a SSD is in JPEG format (though I could change that in the legacy code) and only 240kB large, so performance-wise it should not be a problem.

My initial attempt was to bind the source of the image to the filename of the image inside the `ViewModel` and then use `RaisePropertyChanged` to the GUI to update the image. Unfortunately that does not work. Judging from debugging the legacy code, it is due to the fact that, my GUI C# code is blocking the image file and the legacy program therefore cannot write to it anymore. I also found a thread in SO, suggesting that this is the problem.

So is there a way of achieving what I am trying to do? I have looked at `ImageSource` and `BitmapSource`, since they should allow me to read the file in a non-blocking fashion. But I could not figure out how to integrate them as a source into my `ViewModel`, since they are abstract classes and I was getting the error `Cannot create an instance of the abstract class of interface`.

I would be grateful for any suggestions. A code example would of course be awesome. Here is my code:

ViewModel:

```
public class CameraViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string imageSource;
    public string ImageSource
    {
        get { return imageSource; }
        set {
            if (!(value == imageSource))
            {
                imageSource = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ImageSource");
            }
        }
    }

    public CameraViewModel()
    {
        string fileName = @"./CurrentImage.jpg";
        ImageSource = fileName;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                RaisePropertyChanged("ImageSource");
                Thread.Sleep(33);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

View:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ProgramEditor.Views.CellCameraView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             DataContext="{Binding Camera_VM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
    <Image Name="CameraImage" Height="150" Width="200" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
</UserControl>
```

Code for writing the image in the legacy code. The `DeleteFile`-calls were added for debugging purposes:

```
void WriteCurrentImage(BYTE * pBuffer)
{
    bool rc;
    currentimage = cvCreateImageHeader(cvSize(VideoWidth, VideoHeight),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    currentimage->imageData = (char*)pBuffer;
    rc = DeleteFile( "./CurrentImage_tmp.jpg" ); // to test file access
    cout << "DeleteFile(CurrentImage_tmp) rc:" << rc << endl; // rc = 1; works
    cvSaveImage("./CurrentImage_tmp.jpg" ,currentimage);
    rc = DeleteFile( "./CurrentImage.jpg" ); // to test file access
    cout << "DeleteFile(CurrentImage) rc:" << rc << endl; // rc = 0; fails
    MoveFile("./CurrentImage_tmp.jpg","./CurrentImage.jpg");
    cout << "WriteCurrentImage(pBuffer); called." << endl;
}
```

Comment: The simplest comment that comes to my mind is Can you set a file system watcher on the folder and generate a copy of the image for your new application when the legacy one updates the 'origin' image and use your code on the second image so that you don't block the file used by the legacy code? Also, I remember in a very remote time, years ago we solved the lock on original image in a totally different environment using memory stream to read the image and then working in memory... Just my 2 cents HTH

Comment: Look at the [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) class. It has `Changed` event that seem to solve your problem of monitoring changes to the file.

Comment: Are you saying that you think the `CameraViewModel` class is somehow locking the file, and that some line in your `WriteCurrentImage` is throwing an exception? Which line? Or are you using the actual [ImageSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesource(v=vs.110).aspx) class somewhere? I don't see that class used in your code but your comment implies you are using it somewhere.

Comment: Not surprising this isn't working.  Writing the image to disk isn't the correct thing to do.  Your real question should be on the camera end and how to transmit that, and your code should be from that application.  I'd look into converting a series of images into some kind of video stream supported by the MediaElement control or similar.

Comment: @Quantic Sorry, if my question caused confusion. No, at the moment I am not using ImageSource. I tried to, but did not understand how to use it. In particular I did not know how to create/define a property in my ViewModel to which I could bind the source of my image in the XAML, since from what I found online, the source of the image either needs to be of type `string` or `uri`. That's how I ended up with the code above. I did find some examples using ImageSource, but couldn't quite rap my head around them.

Comment: @packoman The `Source` property of the Image control is of type `ImageSource`. Due to built-in automatic type conversion you can not only bind it to a view model property of type `ImageSource`, but also to properties of type `string`, `Uri` and `byte[]`. Anyway, when your view model has an `ImageSource` property, you can set it to any derived type like `BitmapSource`, `BitmapImage`, `BitmapFrame` etc. Provided that you have a buffer (i.e. a byte array) that holds your encoded image, you could create a MemoryStream from that buffer and pass it to `BitmapFrame.Create` to create a BitmapFrame.